# how to get browse button in image upload form for ckeditor in fuelphp

Tags: ckeditor, fuelphp

I am a newbie in FuelPHP. I am using ckeditor for my content panel according to https://github.com/alwarren/fuelphp.CKEditor_package. I am successful in installing and running ckeditor as pacakage but I am not able to get browse button for image upload. Any idea on how to get this?
Any help/suggestions are welcome.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot be sure about the FuelPHP integration, but CKEditor itself does not come with a built-in file upload capability, you need to [integrate a file manager](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_file_browse_upload) for that (like [CKFinder](http://cksource.com/ckfinder) or one of the other plugins from the [Addons Repository](http://ckeditor.com/addons/plugins/all)). You can also [create your own file uploader and integrate it](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_file_browser_api) with CKEditor.